# How to derive order of magnitude when given any base raised to some exponent?

Tags: exponentiation, estimation

How does one quickly derive order of magnitude without needing to compute the value and count digits?

Say you’re given $26^{25}$ which has order of magnitude $10^{35}$.

How does one get from an exponent of $25$ to $35$ (in a different base)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logarithms:$$26^{25} = 10^x \implies 25\log_{10} 26 = x\implies x \approx 35.37.$$  This tells us that $26^{25}$ has order of magnitude $10^{35}$.

Comment: Very nice question and the same for the answer. +1

Comment: Thank you @dmcmor